# Trying to prove a set to be the union of its singleton sets in Dafny

Tags: set, dafny

I have the following code:

```
ghost function U<T> (S : set<set>) : set
{
if S == {} then {}
else var s := pick (S) ;
     U (S - {s}) + s
} 
ghost function pick<T> (s : set) : T
requires s != {}
{var x :| x in s ; x}
```

But cannot manage to give a suitable body to

```
lemma singletonsU<T> (s : set)
ensures s == U (set x <- s :: {x})
```

In particular when trying induction I seem to need using the function
pick again and this might give a result different from the one obtained
when invoking U.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, that is something you should be concerned with.
Check out the essay "Functions over Set Elements" here for an example of how to deal with that situation.
https://leino.science/dafny-power-user/

```
predicate AllIn<T>(S: set<set<T>>, SU: set<T>) {
  forall xx :: xx in S ==> forall y :: y in xx ==> y in SU
}

predicate AllSingletonSets<T>(S: set<set<T>>) {
  forall ss :: ss in S ==> |ss| == 1
}

ghost function U<T> (S : set<set<T>>) : set<T>
  //requires AllSingletonSets(S); //This is optional it works either way
  ensures AllIn(S, U(S))
{
  if S == {} then 
    // assert AllIn(S, {});
    {}
  else
    var s := pick (S);
    var result := U (S - {s}) + s;
    // assert AllIn(S-{s}, U(S-{s}));
    // var x :| x in s;
    // assert x in s;
    // assert x in  result;

    //This is needed to show extensionality to Dafny
    assert S - {s} + {s} == S;
    // assert AllIn(S, result);
    result
} 

ghost function pick<T> (s : set<T>) : T
  requires s != {}
{
 var x :| x in s;
 x
}
```